# How to hide all tr whom cell has a specific src image

Tags: jquery

I have got a table with around 50 rows, now what I want is to hide all tr from table who has img src = "BadFruit", I am not sure how can I do it efficiently, please guide in right direction,

html

```
"<tr fruit-id='" + someID+ "' class='Row' onclick='DoSomething(" + someID + ")'>" +
"   <div class='Row'>" +
"       <td class='Cell CellInfo'>" +
"           <div class='Title'>" + FruitTitle + "</div>" +
"       </td>" +
"       <td class='Cell CellIcon'>" +
"           <div><img src='" + src + "' alt='" + alt + "' /></div>" +
"       </td>" +
"   </div>" +
"</tr>"
```

I want to do it without page reload

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to select the images which have that source then hide the tr using closest()

```
$('tr img[src="BadFruit"]').closest('tr').hide();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do:

```
$("tr td img[src=BadFruit]").closest("tr").hide();
```